# lex program on counting no of comment lines

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex, lexer

here the program counts the no of comment lines, single line comments and multi line comments and gives a total comments output with a file.txt as input

file.txt

```
//hellow world
/*hello world1*/
/*hello world2
*/
/*hello world3
hello world3.1*/
#include<>
```

count.l

```
    %{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int a=0,b=0,c=0,d;
%}
%%
"//".* {a++;}
"/*" {b++;}
.*"*/" {b--;c++;}
%%
void main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    yylex();
    printf("single line %d \nmultiline %d \n",a,c);
    d=a+c;
    printf("total %d \n",d);
}
```

here the output i get is

./a.out file.txt

```
hello world2 

hello world3



#include<>
single line 1 
multiline 3 
total 4
```

the output that i need to get is just

```
#include<>
single line 1 
multiline 3 
total 4
```

I tried this way too i added `.*` infront of  `"/*"` like this `"/*".*`  then it would delete the `"*/"` in that line  and give me the multi line comment  count as 2. 
i tried various ways but im kinda stuck.

Comment: You probably just want something that matches "." and ignores it

Comment: At some point, you’ll need to recognize that a single line can have several `/* a */ /* b */` comments on it, and that single line comments can extend over multiple lines when continued with a backslash before the newline.  And that’s without getting into backslash newline separating the characters in the comment start and stop symbols.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i posted an answer and it  does work in counting the multiline  comment

Answer (score 4):

This is what start states are for -- they allow you to define a different match rules for different states:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int a=0,b=0,c=0,d;
%}
%x COMMENT    /* an exclusive state that does not also match normal stuff */
%%
"//".*   {a++;}
"/*"     { BEGIN COMMENT; }
<COMMENT>"*/" {c++; BEGIN INITIAL; }
<COMMENT>.    ;
%%
void main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    yylex();
    printf("single line %d \nmultiline %d \n",a,c);
    d=a+c;
    printf("total %d \n",d);
}
```

This will deal properly with things like

```
/*  //  */  ..this is not a comment..
```

that will confuse most other ways of attempting to do this.  It also continues to output newlines that were in comments (so a muliline /*..*/ comments will show up as blank lines.  If you don't want that, you can add a rule for `<COMMENT>\n`

Comment: i tested one case `/*hello //hellow  */ `    
`/* /*hellow */ */` and i get the output `*/` but when i do this in my answer it gives me correct 2 multiline comment. @ChrisDodd

Comment: Hello! How to check if it's a unterminated comment? Thank you!

Comment: ok, found it, just add a rule to sub-state COMMENT:


<COMMENT><<EOF>>     { printf("error.\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

Answer (score 2):

added precise logic to make it work better.

```
    %{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int a=0,c=0,d,e=0;
%}
%%
"/*" {if(e==0)e++;}
"*/" {if(e==1)e=0;c++;}
"//".* {if(e==0)a++;}
. {if(e==0)ECHO;}
%%
void main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    yyout=fopen(argv[2],"w");
    yylex();
    printf("single line %d \nmultiline %d \n",a,c);
    d=a+c;
    printf("total %d \n",d);
}
```

Comment: whats the difference between this and the first code.

Answer (score 0):

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int a=0,b=0,d;
%}
%%
"//".* {a++;}
[/][*][^*]*[*]+([^*/][^*]*[*]+)*[/] {b++;}

%%
void main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    yylex();
    printf("single line %d \nmultiline %d \n",a,b);
    d=a+b;
    printf("total %d \n",d);
}
```

The `.` matches everything else. This does the trick.

Also as pointed on your answer you have just printed the rest of the characters by using `.`.

Comment: wouldn't it delete the #include as well

Comment: @Pollux01.: You want #include?

Comment: yeah i want to delete only comments and keep rest of the c code intact @coderredoc

Comment: i dont really understand how my answer works i did add the . and it gives the desired output.

Comment: @Pollux01.: Your amswer works for this simple input ..try complicated inut you will see it failing. Also you just print whatever is not matched in the rules..thats why works in this case

Comment: i tested one case `/*hello //hellow  */ `    
`/* /*hellow */ */` and i get the output `*/` but when i do this in my answer it gives me correct 2 multiline comment. @coderredoc