# Lex program to remove single line and multi-line comment from a given text

Tags: regex, yacc, lex, text-parsing, lexical-analysis

I am trying to write a lex program which will remove both single line comment and multi-line comment.

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int single=0;
int multi=0;    
%}
%%
"//"([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|" ")* {++single;}
"/*"(.*\n)* "*/" {++multi;}
%%
int main(int argc, int **argv)
{
    yyin=fopen("abc.txt","r");
    yylex();
    printf("no of single line comment = %d ", single);
    printf("no of multi line comment = %d ", multi);
    return 0;
}
```

This program is not able to remove multi-line comment.

Comment: you might need to check for more line end chars...
  LF:    Line Feed, U+000A
 VT:    Vertical Tab, U+000B
 FF:    Form Feed, U+000C
 CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D
 CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)
 NEL:   Next Line, U+0085
 LS:    Line Separator, U+2028
 PS:    Paragraph Separator, U+2029
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Please review these duplicate questions; I'm certain you will find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Count+comments+%5Blex%5D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lex program on counting no of comment lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228599/lex-program-on-counting-no-of-comment-lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are multiple multi-line comments in your abc.txt file then your pattern for multi-line comment would match everything between start of first multi-line comment and end of last multi-line comment. This happens as lex exhibits greedy behavior and will try to match longest prefix of input string. And your pattern for multi-line comment allows /* and */ to be matched by (.*\n)*

Also your code would not detect single line comments that contain any characters other than alphanumeric characters and space (e.g - , ; : etc...).

Change your pattern actions to these and it should achieve your objective.

```
"//".*\n            { ++single; }
"/*"[^*/]*"*/"      { ++multi; }
```

Though above code will still leave some new lines in place of removed multi-line comments. Its bit tricky and I am not able to find out quick solution to remove those new lines.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For flex,

```
"//".* {singleLine++;}
"/*"([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+\/ {multiLine++;}
```

For detailed information: https://blog.ostermiller.org/finding-comments-in-source-code-using-regular-expressions/